# android - Memory management

Tags: java, android, memory-management, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm building a `custom lock` screen and facing issues with `RAM` usage.

RAM occupied by service is `3MB` initially. After lock screen is shown and finished, it increases to `8MB` and keeps increasing with subsequent launches of lock screen.

I am able to reproduce the issue with the following sample code.

MyService.java:

```
public void onCreate() {
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(startIntent);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

`activity_main.xml` and `activity_two.xml` contains only one TextView each.